# pulsating --> pulsatingly pumping - alternatives?

Tags: word-usage

Officially, the adverb 'pulsatingly' derived from 'pulsating' appears not to exist. At least all classical dictionaries (OED, OALD, CALD, LALD, etc. even WordNet v3.1) have no entry.

Theoretically, deriving 'pulsatingly' would be allowed. Hence, I want to know on a scale from 0 (not awkward at all) to 10 (super awkward) how awkward it sounds to use 'pulsatingly pumping into ...'.

Which alternative expressions would you suggest in case that you recommend against using 'pulsatingly pumping'?

Thank you for any valuable input.

Comment: It mostly sounds redundant. *Pulsate* and *pump* seem to describe the same motion.  Maybe more context would help.

Comment: I would give it a 3, but the whole appropriateness issue is very dependent on context. If you decide not to use it, how about "rhythmically" as an alternative.

Comment: @ Juhasz - I tend to disagree, pumping can be a continues action with maintained pressure etc. 

@ LorelC. - thank you. A '3' is good enough to 'introduce' and 'employ' this word in my texts.

Comment: Hugely context-dependent... I'll elaborate in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**Pulsatingly**" is a perfectly reasonable coinage that fulfils all expectations of how the word is formed. Spellchecks won't like it, but that's par for the course. Use it in most places and no-one would bat an eyelid.

"It writhed pulsatingly" is a slightly icky image, but not in any way awkward. "Pulsatingly pumping into", on the other hand, is a little awkward, but really depends on context. In, shall we say, a certain type of fiction, it wouldn't go particularly amiss. It is pleasingly alliterative, as well as an example of *purple prose* (which is similarly alliterative, good coincidence). In case you're not familiar with the concept (and plenty of places online will explain it), it basically refers to excessively florid writing with far more description than necessary, making use of relatively esoteric word choices (like using 'cerulean' rather than 'blue').

Depending on what you're writing, I'd give it anything for 0.5/10 to 6/10.

Oh, and just don't use it in anything which isn't narrative. Fiction, or narrative non-fiction, sure. And poetry, that could be fine, though I foresee difficulty fitting it to metre. Don't include it in a science report.